# Which word occurs most frequently in a text file?

Tags: bash, shell

There's a txt file with a word in every line.

```
"word1"
"word1"
"word2"
"word2"
"word1"
```

I'd like to get which word occurs the most, but I have no idea how to get that, any ideas?

Comment: This would be an easy Perl script to write.  Must you use strictly bash for this?

Comment: Would "WORD1" be considered the same as "word1", or each unique because of the difference in case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Note: See bottom for case-*insensitive* solutions.</sup>

A combination of `sort`, `uniq`, `head`, and `cut` calls is conceptually simplest, and also extensible, but here's **a single-pass `awk` solution** that is probably **more efficient**, although more complex, and **limited to finding only the "winner"** and with **unpredictable ordering in the event of ties**:

```
awk '{ if (++words[$0] > max) { max = words[$0]; maxW=$0 } } END { print maxW }' file
```

With the sample input, this returns `"word2"` (including the double quotes).
Use `print max, maxW` to also output the count.

In the event of a *tie*, among the words that share the max. count, it is *the one whose last occurrence happens to come first in the input file* that "wins" (is output).

---

Here's the **multi-utility equivalent**, which allows **extending the solution to the top N words** and also offers **predictable ordering among the winners in the event of a tie**:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2b | head -n 1 | cut -d\" -f2
word2
```

In the event of a *tie*, the *alphabetically first* word among the ones that share the max. count is printed.

Note: For convenience, the above uses `cut` to extract the word without the enclosing double quotes.

To preserve the double quotes, use `awk` instead of `cut`:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2b | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
"word2"
```

Omitting the last pipeline segment and modifying `head`'s `-n 1` option allows you to see how many occurrences of each word were found and to **find the top N words (including double quotes)**; e.g., to see the top 10 (with the sample input, you only get 2):

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2b | head -n 10
   3 "word1"
   2 "word2"
```

---

A **note on the `sort` call**, `sort -k1,1nr -k2b`:

Explicitly stating the sort fields is good practice - both for efficiency and to avoid unexpected results:

- `-k1,1nr` sorts primarily by *1st* whitespace-separated field (`k1,1`), numerically (`-n`), in reverse order (`r`).

  - Note the explicit *end* index in `-k1,1`, as just `-k1` would sort everything *starting from* field 1 *through the end of the line*.
- `-k2b` then sorts secondarily starting with the *2nd* whitespace-separated field *through the end of the line* (`-k2`), ignoring leading whitespace (`b`; the whitespace that separates the fields) and performing *lexical* (alphabetic) sorting.

Newer versions of *GNU* `sort` (not the one on macOS, unfortunately) have a helpful `--debug` option that visualizes how each line is broken into keys during sorting.

---

Using just `sort` or `sort -nr` to sort the *whole* line is tempting, but doesn't necessarily yield the expected results:

- Just `sort` sorts the whole line lexically (alphabetically), in ascending order; due to the padded fixed-width nature of the word counts in the 1st field the results are still effectively numerically sorted, but in the event of a tie it is the alphabetically *last* word that is output.
- Just `sort -rn` applies numerical sorting to the whole line, in descending order. With numerical sorting field parsing stops at the longest prefix that can be interpreted as a number, an implicit feature called last-resort comparison (can be turned off with `-n`) sorts the rest of the line *alphabetically* (in reverse order, in this case). It is therefore also the alphabetically *last* word that is output in the event of a tie.

---

**Case-insensitive variants**:

Note that the input is transformed to all-lowercase for simplicity.

- `awk`

```
awk '{ $0=tolower($0); if (++wds[$0] > max) { max = wds[$0]; maxW=$0 } } END { print maxW }' file
```

- `sort` + `uniq` + `head` + `cut`

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < file |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2b | head -n 1 | cut -d\" -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort meh.txt | uniq -c
```

Where *meh.txt* is your file.  This gives the count for each word.

Running this on your text gives:

```
3 "word1"
2 "word2"
```

If you only need the most common, you can get it with:

```
sort meh.txt | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1
```

(There maybe be a shorter way to do this, but I don't know it.)

Answer (score 1):

try with something like this: `cat test | sort | uniq -c`

- cat reads the file
- sort sorts it for uniq command
- uniq with -c "prefix lines by the number of occurrences"

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the top word with no of occurences use something like this.

`sort test.txt|uniq -c|sort -nr|head -1`

you can change the above to find the top n words. e.g to get the top 3 words

`sort test.txt|uniq -c|sort -nr|head -3`